# How to override $value$plusargs

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Is there a way to force a value to the return value of `$value$plusargs` by doing it in the code itself instead of passing the argument from the simulator command?

Example situation: I have a BFM written in verilog that calls `$value$plusargs` in multiple places. I want to restrict the user to just do only one specific configuration which can be controlled by the `$value$plusargs`. I can not modify the BFM, and I don't want user to control the plus-argument. The idea is that I will write a wrapper and add the some code to force those plus-arguments to specific values.
So is there a way in verilog code to override/force the return value of `value$plusarg` for any particular argument?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the LRM that would let you do this. However, you can write a PLI routine (ie. in C/C++) that has the same name as a system task/function, and this will be used in preference to the system one. You should get Sutherland's book (0-7923-7658-7) if you haven't done a PLI app before.